# Couple of questions about spring quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm thinking of building spring quartz into my spring mvc web application. I have a few questions about it that I could not properly find an answer.

1. If I want to use cron triggers for spring quartz does quartz execute the job using java system time or the operating system time?
2. I am planning to have a properties file to hold all of my cron triggers. If someone goes and changes a cron trigger for an ad-hoc execution of a job will quartz automatically pick up the changes in the file? Or is there a way for me to tell quartz how to do this if it is not default behavior.
3. I have been reading about spring batch admin console recently. Sounds like a nice gui tool to reschedule jobs. Can it be used to make ad-hoc changes to crontab triggers? Or is there another gui tool I could use to manage the job triggers?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quartz

1. Quartz uses custom thread scheduler (`org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler`) which use java system time. It can integrate `commonj` interface to be JEE (WAS and Weblogic) interoperable.
2. Reload configuration: read [Quartz: How to reload jobs and triggers with org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508252/quartz-how-to-reload-jobs-and-triggers-with-org-quartz-plugins-xml-xmlschedulin)
3. Spring batch admin console is for spring batch and is bale to monitor batches activity

### Reload configuration Using API

Generally speaking you can use [quartz API](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example3) programmatically (I use them):

```
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName("myJob");
    job.setJobClass(MyJob.class);

    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    trigger.setName("myTriggerName");
    trigger.setCronExpression("0/30 * * * * ?");


    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

these APIs provide you fine control.

### Reload configuration JMX way

You can control the Qurtz scheduler through `RemoteMBeanScheduler`:

> An implementation of the Scheduler interface that remotely proxies all method calls to the equivalent call on a given QuartzScheduler instance, via JMX.