# Quartz jobs not starting through XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

It's been two days I'm trying to figure how to make things work. I have a Java Spring application and I want to use the XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin to run the jobs in my application. This is the Job class I have defined:

```
public class MyJob implements Job
{
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyJob.class.getName());

    public MyJob() { 
        System.out.println("My Job");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "My Job");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "my job fired");
        System.out.println("my job fired"); 

    }

}
```

Pretty simple. The following is the quartz.properties file I defined to fire the previously defined job:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: MySchedulerForMyJob
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true

org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class: org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class: org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames: quartz_jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound: true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval: 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 3
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Now let's see how I defined the quartz_jobs.xml file I am telling Quartz to look at:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
  version="1.8">
    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>myJob</name>
            <group>MYJOB_GROUP</group>
            <description>This job is a job</description>
            <job-class>com.myProject.MyJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>myTrigger</name>
                <group>MYTRIGGER_GROUP</group>
                <job-name>myJob</job-name>
                <job-group>MYJOB_GROUP</job-group>
                <!-- trigger every 5 seconds -->
                <cron-expression>0/5 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Basically what I expect on startup is that I see the message "my job fired" printed every 5 seconds. I don't see anything of the sort, suggesting that the job did not start. The following is what I get as output in my console:

```
2018-09-11 10:02:39,944 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl] - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2018-09-11 10:02:39,944 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.3 created.
2018-09-11 10:02:39,945 - INFO  - [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore] - RAMJobStore initialized.
2018-09-11 10:02:39,945 - INFO  - [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2018-09-11 10:02:39,945 - INFO  - [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.3
2018-09-11 10:02:39,946 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@ad570f2
2018-09-11 10:02:40,220 - WARN  - [org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils] - Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
2018-09-11 10:02:40,319 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Quartz Initializer Servlet loaded, initializing Scheduler...
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl] - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.3 created.
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore] - RAMJobStore initialized.
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler 'MySchedulerForMyJob' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.3
2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler MPListScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler has been started...
Storing the Quartz Scheduler Factory in the servlet context at key: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY
```

This suggests me that the `quartz.properties` file is correctly read since it says `2018-09-11 10:02:40,326 - INFO  - [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler 'MySchedulerForMyJob' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'` citing the correct name of the scheduler I gave in `quartz.properties`.

What could be wrong in all this to make the job not start?

Comment: every five seconds `0/5 0 0 ? * * *` - see  https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: Seems like both the expressions work the same (given the description of the expression)... anyways no prints even by changing 0 to *. As you can see I don't even see the logs of the creation of the job (assuming the constructor is called when the job is instantiated)

Comment: @ScaryWombat just saw you edited your comment. The expression you suggest starts the job after midnight? Since it seems not to work I just tried `* * * ? * * *` which the expression generator says it's every second but again no logs are printed

Comment: *but again no logs are printed* - logging problem?

Comment: Not sure? I don't know if I am expected to see the `sysout` or the `LOGGER` logs being printed on the console. I expect them to be printed since every tutorial suggests to have a logger... but I don't see them. You are saying the job is running and I'm logging in the wrong way? If that is the case, how do you suggest to track if the job is running?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I added an action in the Job that writes on a database, but nothing is written so I suppose the job is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

I guess still you have some issues with the quartz.properties.I have doubt on the below configuration. Excuse me if that not solved your issues

org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class:org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin

It should be `

> **LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin**

`

```
org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
```

OR

> **LoggingJobHistoryPlugin**

```
org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
```

You have mis configured that property. Have a look at this for using those features. [link](https://dzone.com/articles/hidden-treasure-quartz)

Else first try with the simple example that donot have any thread pool or logging job history.Some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508252/quartz-how-to-reload-jobs-and-triggers-with-org-quartz-plugins-xml-xmlschedulin) . If possible please change : to = in properties file. I know that is not a problem. Just a try

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I think the problem is that it does not read the quartz_job.xml file. If I change that with "random_name_jobs.xml" (a file that does not exist) it still runs without any problem. Do you think I should specify absolute path?

Comment: Yes please give a try.If absolute path you can change cron expression also if required .

Comment: It seems like even if I remove the file from the directory it does not complain. Even if I specified failOnFileNotFound at true. Why is that?